# What are the requirements to host an ASP.Net MVC2 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Are there any special requirements needed to host an ASP.Net MVC2 application?

I'm making an application that will be hosted locally in the server area of my University. I can use either ASP.Net or MVC2, but I'd much rather use MVC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you just need .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and an IIS version that runs on it.